How to vectorize this nested for loop?
I am finding the cylindrical projection of an image given the camera's intrinsic matrix and the distortion coefficients. After finding the warpped coordinates, I need to find the image value for those coordinates and assign them to an empty wrapped image. I would like to vectorize the nested for loop written at the end. I tried with sub2ind, had series of errors and gave up. Below is the code:
clc; close all; clear;

% Inputs
fileName = 'checker.jpg';

% Add grid line
add_grid = 0;

% Focal lengths
fx = 50;
fy = 50;

% Read image
image = (imread(fileName));

% Get image size
[ydim, xdim, bypixs] = size(image);

% Camera intrinsics
K = [fx, 0, xdim/2; 0, fy, ydim/2; 0, 0, 1];

% Distortion coefficients [k1, k2, k3, p1, p2]
DC = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

% Get distrotion coefficients
fx = K(1,1);
fy = K(2,2);
k1 = DC(1);
k2 = DC(2);
k3 = DC(3);
p1 = DC(4);
p2 = DC(5);

% Get image size
[ydim, xdim, bypixs] = size(image);

% Initialize an array
imageCylindrical = uint8(zeros(ydim, xdim, bypixs));

% Get the center of image
xc = xdim/2;
yc = ydim/2;

% Create X and Y coordinates grid
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:xdim, 1:ydim);

% Perform the cylindrical projection
theta = (X - xc) / fx;
h = (Y - yc) / fy;

% Cylindrical coordinates to Cartesian
xcap = sin(theta);
ycap = h;
zcap = cos(theta);

xyz_cap = cat(3, xcap, ycap, zcap);
xyz_cap = reshape(xyz_cap,[],3);

% Normalized coords
xyz_cap_norm = (K * xyz_cap')';
xn = xyz_cap_norm(:,1) ./ xyz_cap_norm(:,3);
yn = xyz_cap_norm(:,2) ./ xyz_cap_norm(:,3);

% Radial and tangential distortion 
r = xn.^2 + yn.^2;
xd_r = xn .* (1 + k1 * r.^2 + k2 * r.^4 + k3 * r.^6);
yd_r = yn .* (1 + k1 * r.^2 + k2 * r.^4 + k3 * r.^6);

xd_t = 2 * p1 * xn .* yn + p2 * (r.^2 + 2 * xn.^2);
yd_t = p1 * (r.^2 + 2 * yn.^2) + 2 * p2 * xn .* yn;

xd = xd_r + xd_t;
yd = yd_r + yd_t;

% Reshape and clip coordinates
xd = reshape(ceil(xd),[ydim, xdim]);
yd = reshape(ceil(yd),[ydim, xdim]);
mask = xd > 0 & xd <= xdim & yd > 0 & yd <= ydim;

% Get masked coordinates
xd = xd .* mask;
yd = yd .* mask;

% Get projections
for i = 1:ydim
    for j = 1:xdim
        if yd(i,j) ~= 0 || xd(i,j)~=0
            imageCylindrical(i,j,:) = image(yd(i,j), xd(i,j),:);
        end
    end
end

Here is the sample image:

Any help is appreciated!

How many pixels satisfy yd(i,j) ~= 0 || xd(i,j)~=0? Is it a large fraction of a small fraction of all pixels?

It is quite large if the image size is very large. Therefore, a considerable amount of pixels satisfy.

idx = find(yd | xd); imageCylindrical(idx) = image(sub2ind( size(image), yd(idx), xd(idx) ));  seems to work

It produces an error:
Out of range subscript.

Error in image2cylindrical_v1 (line 83)
imageCylindrical(idx) = image(sub2ind( size(image), yd(idx), xd(idx) ));


How about idx = find(yd | xd); imageCylindrical = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(k) image(yd(k), xd(k),:), idx, 'UniformOutput', false));

@TonyMathew, it again throws an error: ```Index in position 1 exceeds array bounds. Index must not exceed 160.
Error in image2cylindrical_v1>@(k)image(yd(k),xd(k),:) (line 83)
imageCylindrical = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(k) image(yd(k), xd(k),:), idx, 'UniformOutput', false));
Error in image2cylindrical_v1 (line 83)
imageCylindrical = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(k) image(yd(k), xd(k),:), idx, 'UniformOutput', false));```
